# How can i join two tables with two columns that refers the same column in the second table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have two tables to join.

First table has two columns

1. User ID of the record owner.
2. User ID of the assigned user.

And the second table has userId and username columns. These two columns of first table refers to the same column of the same table. I want to see both user names in a view but I can't get those at the same time. How should I do that?

Edit

```
select
    TASKID,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_AT,
    ASSIGNED_USER,
    USERNAME ,
    DEADLINE,
    USERNAME
from 
    TASKS
inner join 
    USERS on ASSIGNED_USER = USERID
```

I can get username of `ASSIGNED_USER`'s username with the query above. I've tried the second for getting both usernames but it didn't work

```
select
    TASKID,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_AT,
    ASSIGNED_USER,
    USERNAME ,
    DEADLINE,
    USERNAME
from 
    TASKS
inner join 
    USERS on ASSIGNED_USER = USERID and CREATED_BY = USERID
```

It returns an empty result.

Comment: *"but i can't get those at the same time"* why not? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to join to user twice once for CREATED_BY and once for ASSIGNED_USER:

```
select
    TASKID,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_AT,
    ASSIGNED_USER,
    USERNAME ,
    DEADLINE,
    USERNAME
from TASKS
inner join USERS u1 on ASSIGNED_USER = u1.USERID 
inner join USERS u2 on CREATED_BY = u2.USERID
```

Answer (score 0):

Join USERS twice to decode different references

```
select TASKID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_AT, ASSIGNED_USER, au.USERNAME assignedUser_Name, DEADLINE,  uc.USERNAME createdByUser_Name
from TASKS t
inner join USERS au
on t.ASSIGNED_USER = au.USERID 
inner join USERS uc
on t.CREATED_BY = uc.USERID
```